# Storing form data in cache

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, caching

There is a requirement that i have stored web page in cache which include form. if internet is disconnected (because of any reason) still user can open that web page. now what i want is form data should be stored in cache (if internet is disconnected) and later data should be stored automatically in database when internet connected. how is this possible? is there any other way to make this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with "other way", did you try something which didnt work out ?

Comment: I have just store webpage in cache. now i want to store form data in cache if internet is disconnected. After that form data(which stored in cache) should be stored in database.